# Having trouble getting Google Captcha working

Tags: php, html, captcha

I'm currently creating a contact form and the form requires a captcha to be completed to reduce spam, I've followed tutorials on how to use the captchas in my code, but yet everytime its not working, hopefully someone can help here. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
 <body>
 <hgroup>
 <h1>Contact Us</h1>
 <?php if(isset($_GET['CaptchaPass'])){ ?>
 <h3>Your message was sent, you should recieve an email back within 24 
 hours.</h3>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php if(isset($_GET['CaptchaFail'])){ ?>
 <h3>Captcha Failed. Please try again!</h3>
 <?php } ?>
 </hgroup>
 <form method='post' action='contactver.php'>
 <div class="group">
 <input type="text" name="name"><span class="highlight"></span><span 
 class="bar"></span>
 <label>Name</label>
 </div>
 <div class="group">
 <input type="email" name="email"><span class="highlight"></span><span 
 class="bar"></span>
 <label>Email</label>
 </div>
 <div class="group">
 <input type="phone" name="phone"><span class="highlight"></span><span 
 class="bar"></span>
 <label>Phone No.</label>
 </div>
 <div class="group">
 <input type="message" name="message"><span class="highlight"></span><span 
 class="bar"></span>
 <label>Message</label>
 </div>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-
sitekey="My Key, want to keep private :)"></div>
<button type="submit" name="login" class="button buttonBlue">Submit Message
<div class="ripples buttonRipples"><span class="ripplesCircle"></span></div>
</button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
$firstname = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$privatekey = "Want to keep this private :)";

$response = file_get_contents($url."?
secret".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-
response']."&remoteip".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$data = json_decode($response);

if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true) {

echo("Pass");

}else {

header('Location: contact.php?CaptchaFail=true');
echo("Fail");
}


}
```

Comment: I don't see redirect to `?CaptchaPass` in your PHP.

Comment: @tilz0R I didn't add in this sorry but it is there and not working, any other fixes?? :(

Comment: Why don't you check `$data` object from Google? If you do `var_dump` or `print_r` of it, you will probably see response.

Comment: @tilz0R object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["success"]=> bool(false) ["error-codes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(20) "missing-input-secret" } }   Any fix? :(

Comment: Yeah. Read docs on Google captcha which request to send.

Comment: @tilz0R Where would i find that though? :)

Comment: Now you are trolling.

Comment: @tilz0R Honestly not, I've never used a captcha and don't know what I'm doing otherwise i wouldn't be asking :(

Comment: @tilz0R You gonna help man? :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JavaScript for google captcha validation  before form submit .

```
var v = grecaptcha.getResponse();
if(v.length == 0){
    document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML="You can't leave Captcha Code empty";
    error = false;
}else{
    document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML="";
}  
if(error !== false){
    $('#yourformid').submit();
}

return false;
```

Comment: Really doesn't answer a question.

Comment: Could you do it in PhP? :)

Comment: of-course  after reading your php code . if you slightly change in your code.  
$data = json_decode($response);

if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true) {  
to $status= json_decode($response, true);
                if($status['success']){

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an issue with this line:

```
if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true)
```

It should be:

```
if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success===true)
```

Other than that, I would suggest using the Google Composer library (https://github.com/google/recaptcha) to validate the recaptcha. It will solve you lines of code and headaches since they will keep it up to date.